# Figure beside itemize environment?

Tags: floats, itemize, wrapfigure

I am struggling to fit a figure in the right side of the page next to itemize environment. My point is that it is practical to use empty space beside itemize for figures. Any sugestions?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a (full) minimal compilable code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way using tikz overlays (If I got the question correct):

```
\documentclass{article}      
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\section{Foo}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{itemize}
    \item \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture] \coordinate(Here);\node[shift={(-.6cm,-0.65cm)}] at(Here){\includegraphics[width=0.5cm, height=2cm]{example-image-a}}; \end{tikzpicture}Test
    \item Test 2
    \item Test 3
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: If "beside" is the other direction, then, by changing in the `shift` parameter you can place the text anywhere you like.

Comment: Any chance I can add a caption?

Comment: The way to add a caption is in @Ignasi's answer by using `caption` package and `\captionof` command inside a minipage. But if you really want the figure to be on the left and no extra space added, you have to use tikz overlays or something simmilar. If you just want to add the figure to the right and there are no big items in itemize, @Ignasi's answer is easier and better

Answer (score 6):

You don't need `TikZ`, only two `minipages` and a `captionof` command for the non floating figure caption.

```
\documentclass{article}      
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\section{Foo}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Test 1
    \item Test 2
    \item Test 3
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\captionof{figure}{This is a nice image}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very useful for me today. Thanks!